# Best solution to render several objects without overlapping

Tags: opengl, 3d

I just can’t figure out how to do it better. On the 3D scene there are several objects in one plane, and I need to render them in such a way that when they actually intersect, one object is displayed completely on top of another object.

To make it clearer, for example, I have such 3d scene:
[image]

and I need to do this for all objects:
[image]

The only thing that comes to my mind is to clear the Z-buffer every time after each drawing of the object:

```
1) Render object1.
2) Clear Z-buffer.
3) Render object2.
3) Clear Z-buffer.
......
N) Render objectN.
N+1) Clear Z-buffer.
```

But as I understand it, such solution will be extremely costly in performance. Is there any way to repeat this effect somehow with the help of a stencil buffer or in some other way?

Comment: because flushing a hundred times the z-buffer in one frame is pretty expensive? Or not? I can use glScissor, to clean only the necessary part of the z-buffer.

Also my solution are not suitable for instancing ....

Comment: @httpdigest: If the objects in question are not convex, you can't rely on face culling to sort out intra-object Z ordering.

Comment: Yes, the whole problem is that objects can intersect themselves, so just turning off writing to the z-buffer does not work. But sorting by triangles - I think this is even more expensive than clearing part of the z-buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have knowledge about the number of potentially overlapping objects beforehand, you can make use of `glDepthRange`. Sort the objects by depth, then for object `i` (in ascending order, i.e. smallest `i` is the closest object) issue `glDepthRange((float)i/N, (float)(i+1)/N)`, where `N` is the number of objects.

Note that the order in which you draw the objects doesn't matter, as depth testing is preserved and layering is explicit by the depth range.

Comment: Aw, man, that seems to be what I need! Thank you very much! I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Painter's Algorithm: For each new camera viewpoint sort the (convex) models by distance from centroid to the camera position, disable the depth testing and render all of them from back to front.

To avoid sorting the objects by centroid every time you can use a spatial Tree: it could be an Oct-tree, Quad-tree, BSP-tree, AABB-tree or others. The leaves of the tree point to your objects and internal nodes subdivide the space that separate them. You can traverse those trees in back-to-front order from any camera position at rendering time.

The BSP-tree is the most flexible one since you can choose the planes that best separate your objects from each other at will. Even if the objects overlapp you just define a plane splitting them and classify them to be entirely at one side of the plane and it will work as you want.